# Humidity setting for vacant house

Tags: humidifier

What should the humidity  be set at a vacant house in Minnesota January through May

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to spend a bunch of money on HVAC for a vacant house, 50% (or "between 40 and 60%")

Else, drain the plumbing, put RV antifreeze in the sink and toilet traps, turn off the furnace and let the humidity be what it is. Far less costly for 5 months.